# Finding out how out how much is 100%

Tags: fractions, percentages

I know 14% is 41. So how much is 100%? I know it is simple math, but... you know how it is being out of school for a few years. If at all possible, I'd like to see the equation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the total value, so we have:

$14\%x = 41 \implies 0.14x = 41$

From here, you should get the value of $x$ and that would be your 100$

Answer (score 0):

**Virtually all** percent problems can be written in English as $$\text{X percent of Y is Z}$$where you know two of the three quantities $\text{ X, Y, and Z}$,

and the English translates into math the same way every time: "percent" becomes $\frac1{100}$, "of " becomes $\times$, and "is" becomes $=$.  So we get:$$\frac{X}{100}\times Y=Z$$In this case, you know $X$ and $Z$

(Other languages will work also)

Answer (score -1):

$$ \frac{14%}{41} = \frac{100%}{\text{answer}} $$

$$ \text{answer} = 100×41÷14 $$